# "'<' not supported between int and NoneType" Error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working on generating bifurcation diagrams. I can generate them just fine with the equations

```
rx(1-x)
rsin(\pi x)
```

but when I switch to these, it throws the aforementioned error.

```
f(x)=2rx for 0 < x < 1/2
2r(1-x) for 1/2 < x < 1
```

[image]

I can't think of where the error might be coming from. I tried reducing n and printing out x, but that didn't help me narrow it down. It would stall on me, but I can't think of what would make it do so. It's iterating through x and r, which are both real numbers.

I built a previous version based off of this tutorial: https://ipython-books.github.io/121-plotting-the-bifurcation-diagram-of-a-chaotic-dynamical-system/ . I couldn't figure out exactly what was going on with it when I needed to switch to the same set of equations. So I decided to rebuild it to try and understand it better.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def sequence(r, x):
    #these two work well
    #return r * x * (1 - x)
    #return r * math.sin(math.pi * x)
    
    if 0 < x and x < 1/2:
        return 2 * r * x
    
    if 1/2 < x and x < 1:
        return 2 * r * (1 - x)

rmin = 0.5
rmax = 1.5
n = 6000
r = []

for i in range(n):
    r.append(rmin + (rmax - rmin) * i / n)

iterations = 1000
last = 100

x0 = 0.1

bifurcation = []

for i in r:
    points = []
    points.append(sequence(i, x0))
    
    for j in range(iterations):
        x = sequence(i, points[j - 1])
        
        points.append(x)
        
        if j >= iterations - last:
            bifurcation.append(x)
    
plt.plot(bifurcation, 'ko', markersize = 0.1, alpha = 0.25)
plt.show()
```

Comment: At same point `x` becomes `None`. Add a `try` `except` clause around your if statement, when it hits an exception print `x`.. It is `None`. If this is correct, you need to `pass` the exception, if not you need to do more digging into why `x` is `None`

Comment: I always forget error catching. It was an incredibly brief topic in my degree and was never enforced. Unfortunately. I will it in! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add some point, you're calling `sequence(1.0, 0.5)`, which returns `None` because it falls off the bottom.  This value then gets passed as x in a later call to `sequence`, and you get the indicated error.

Sorry, your code is a little bit too convoluted for me to figure out anything beyond that.

Comment: Right. In my previous solution, I used numpy.where(...) for the two equations. And then added the two solutions and removed the zeroes with ```return x[x != 0]```. Now I feel silly. Hopefully it will be as simple as an if statement when I get back to it in a few hours.

Comment: Also. What do you mean convoluted? I am always open to improving my coding.

Comment: Just that it wasn't obvious to me what the flow of the program was.  I could tell `x` was both an output of the function `sequence` and an input to it, but I couldn't quite figure out how this works.  I'm sure if I actually knew what it was you were doing in your code, it would all make sense.

Comment: As an additional matter, I highly recommend that you modify `sequence`.  A function that is supposed to return a value should never have a fall-through-and-return-None path.  Either return some sensible value or have an assertion that you can't reach there.

Answer (score 0):

pay attention to your function `sequence`, for some cases it does not return anything (which implicitly actually returns `None`), in that case you append None to youe list, and further send it back to the function, as you can see from the modified example:

```
def sequence(r, x):
    #these two work well
    #return r * x * (1 - x)
    #return r * math.sin(math.pi * x)
    if 0 < x and x < 1/2:
        return 2 * r * x
    
    if 1/2 < x and x < 1:
        return 2 * r * (1 - x)
    
    print(f"return None, because {x} was not in any of cases above")


# return None, because 0.5 was not in any of cases above
```

further when you call it again, you compare with `None`, handle all cases in function and return legal values and it will work!